# Dynamic XY scatter chart

Tags: excel, charts

I am trying to create a dynamic XY scatter chart. Basically the chart is based on two columns. The first is the client name and the second a number which I want to plot on the XY scatter graph. The client name will be in the legend entry and the horizontal access will contain the value.
What I need however is a dynamic chart that changes based on the number of clients I have. The problem I have is that because the legend series is the one that changes I can't use a named range and if I put it in the Chart data range it changes to the exact reference. Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: When you say you can't use a named range, could you use a dynamic range? eg http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/DynamicRanges.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use a macro in your `Worksheet_Change` event to dynamically update a named range using `Range('First Cell of the Data Range').CurrentRegion`